# I want to create only one audio player instance please

Tags: javascript, audio

I have used the embed tag to make a playlist. The player is generated each time you click the audio of the list. When you listen to the selected file and then press one of the other files in the list, the player is eliminated and a new player appears.

However, instead, I want to show only one player, and reuse it.
Perhaps because I continue to emerge are as bottom.insertBefore.
I want to make a single player.

```
if (agent.indexOf("chrome") != -1 || agent.indexOf("opera") != -1) {                            
            var audio = document.createElement('audio');
            audio.setAttribute('id', 'audio'); 
            audio.type = 'audio/wav';
            audio.src = files[current];
            audio.autoplay = true;

            a.setAttribute('onclick', 'playlistClick(0)');
            a2.setAttribute('onclick', 'playlistClick(1)');
            a3.setAttribute('onclick', 'playlistClick(2)');

            bottom.appendChild(pop_tit01);
            bottom.appendChild(audio);
            bottom.appendChild(mp3_player);
            bottom.appendChild(re_txt);

        } else {                                        
            var pop_tit01 = document.createElement('dl');
            pop_tit01.setAttribute('class', 'pop_tit01');

            var dt = document.createElement('dt');

            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.setAttribute('src', 'images/img/sample_img05.jpg');

            var dd = document.createElement('dd');

            var strong = document.createElement('strong');
            var str = document.createTextNode("default");
            var strdd = document.createTextNode("click list");

            //top
            dt.appendChild(img);
            strong.appendChild(str);
            dd.appendChild(strong); 
            dd.appendChild(strdd);

            //top image             
            pop_tit01.appendChild(dt);
            pop_tit01.appendChild(dd);  

            bottom.appendChild(pop_tit01);

            a.setAttribute('onclick', 'playlistclick(0)');
            a2.setAttribute('onclick', 'playlistclick(1)');
            a3.setAttribute('onclick', 'playlistclick(2)');

            //bottom.appendChild(audio);
            bottom.appendChild(re_txt);
        }

        function playlistclick(src) {
                            var audio = document.createElement('embed');
                            audio.setAttribute('id', 'audio');
                            audio.height = "50";
                            audio.width = "400";
                            audio.controls = false;
                            audio.type = "audio/wav";

                            bottom.insertBefore(audio, re_txt);

                            current = src;
                            audio.src = files[current]; 
        }
```

Comment: In line 2, you create a var to hold the audio element. Why not separate that out with some logic that checks to see if you already have an audio element? This way you wouldn't receive duplicates, and you can reuse the same `audio` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just check to see if those elements already exist before blindly creating them every time you enter your functions.

```
if (agent.indexOf("chrome") != -1 || agent.indexOf("opera") != -1) { 
    // Before you start, check for an element with an "audio" ID.
    // Something similar can be added everywhere else.
    if (document.findElementById('audio')) {
        return;
    }

    var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    audio.setAttribute('id', 'audio'); 
    // ....
}
```

Comment: I do not want to continue the embed output. .
I hope when audio is playing out once .